# Finding statistical fashion on Java. Help me to find mistakes in my code

Tags: java, statistics

I need to write my own function that returns the most repeated value of the array.
I have an array, and I need to count statistical fashion (mode, which is the most repeated value in array) and I don't know why it's not working.

I create 2 arrays:

The first contains the values, and the second array I want to insert how many times each value from first array are repeated, then by my function, `findmax`, I search for the biggest index of repeated value, and then finally show a message with the mode.

```
public int findmax(Integer [] somearray) { 
    int max = somearray[0];
    int z=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < somearray.length; i++) {
        if (somearray[i]>max){
            max = somearray[i];
            z = i;
        }
    }        

    return z;
}

private void myModaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Double [] myarray = new Double[dsTable.getRowCount()];
    Integer [] myarray2 = new Integer[dsTable.getRowCount()];

    for (int i=0; i < myarray.length; i++){
        myarray[i] = (Double)dsTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0);
    }

    java.util.Arrays.sort(myarray);
    for (int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.mainPanel,((Double)myarray[i]));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < myarray2.length; i++){
        myarray2[i]=0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < myarray.length; j++){
            if (myarray[i] == myarray[j]){
                myarray2[i]++;
            }
        }  
    }
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.mainPanel,myarray[findmax(myarray2)]);              
}
```

The result of program is first value of the first array.

Comment: What's not working? Do you get exceptions? Bad output? No output? Does it fail to compile?

Comment: I'm not sure if you might want to put this in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Iterate over the incoming array and record the values in a `Map`, with the key being the value from the array, and the value being the number of times that it appears. You can then find ties for the mode (e.g., `[1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 3]` ties with both `1` and `3`).

Comment: @Augusto: Don't think its meant for *codereview*. The OP wants help to *to find mistakes in my code*...but then again as Ishtar rightly points out....it is pretty hard to understand what is not working!

Comment: It's not returns the result. It returns first value.
my array: 65,67,69,70,71,72,72,73,75,77,79,80

Comment: Also, be aware that you are checking for object reference equality with `myarray[i] == myarray[j]`, not for value equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your homework, so I'll give you some pointers to help you out.

- Consider using a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Here the key would be numbers in your first array and value would be *count* for each value that you encounter. *So the first time you encounter a number, add it to the map, and for every subsequent time, you just increment the value*
- Once you've this map, it would be trivial to find out the key which has the maximum value. Also note that there might be more than one key that can have that maximal value, so you might want to handle that case as well.

One more hint: *The way you're incrementing your second array seems incorrect. You might want to revisit your logic over there as well.*

Answer (score 0):

Is it homework? Because you are reinventing the wheel poorly. Why don't you try with [Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/stat.html)? They have many statistics classes that can do most things for you and they are pretty simple:

```
DescriptiveStatistics statistics = new DescriptiveStatistics(someArray.lentgh);

for( Integer value : someArray){
  statistics.addValue( value.doubleValue() );
}

// magick here
statistics.getMax();
```

Comment: I need the most repeated value of the first array!